# How to on selected letter from alphabet show text for that letter? Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I'm pulling the text from the JASON. Now I want to click on the letter to show text for that letter. Example if I click on A i want to show text for A. Example of my json is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "letter": "A",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget rutr ."
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "letter": "B",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
},
```

Now i looped though json to show 'A', 'B', 'C' and that work fine:

```
   const alphabetHolder = document.querySelector(".alphabet")
    module.data.forEach((letter) => {
        console.log(letter.letter)
        const p = document.createElement("p")
        p.innerHTML = letter.letter
        alphabetHolder.appendChild(p)
    })
```

Question my again: How on clicked letter show text from that json?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`:

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "letter": "A",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget rutr ."
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "letter": "B",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
}];

const findByLetter = l => (arr.find(({ letter }) => letter == l) || { text: "" }).text;

console.log(findByLetter("A"));
console.log(findByLetter("B"));
```

Comment: How to show on click ?? I not sure did can work property?

Comment: Just add a click listener and call the function - simple.

Comment: It's simple - you pass a letter, and it returns the text of the object with the matching letter, or an empty string if no matching letter is found.

Comment: `= l =>` - The `l` is the letter passed.

Comment: I don't undarstand you.